# Errors writing a dataframe to DB2 using Pandas to_sql

Tags: python-3.x, pandasql

I am trying to load data from a pandas dataframe to an IBM DB2 Data Warehouse environment.  The table already exists so I am just appending rows to the table.  I have built the dataframe to mirror every field in the table exactly.

I am using Pandas to_sql method to try to get the dataframe data to the table.  I already know that I am connected to the database, but when I run the code I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

I didn't see anything in the pandas documentation about having to define a cursor when using to_sql.  Any help would be appreciated.

I tried writing a direct sql insert statement rather than using to_sql but couldn't get that to work properly either.  I already have a to_csv method where I'm writing the dataframe to a csv file, so I would like to just use the same dataframe to insert to the table.

I cannot add too much code as this is a company project, but the table has 15 columns with differing datatypes (decimal, character, timestamp).

This is my to_sql statement:

```
`output_df.to_sql(name='PD5', con=self.db2_conn, schema='REBTEAM', if_exists='append', index=False)`
```

I expect the table to be loaded with the rows.  The test file I'm using has 880 rows, so I would expect the table to have 880 rows.

Here is the entire error message I'm getting:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\dt24358\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2531
    dtype=dtype, method=method)
UserWarning: The spaces in these column names will not be changed. In pandas versions < 0.14, spaces were converted to underscores.
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dt24358\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\dt24358\Scripts\Pricing Tool\Rebate_GUI_SQL.py", line 100, in <lambda>
    command= lambda: self.submit_click(self.path, self.fileName, self.save_location, self.request_var.get(), self.execution_var.get(),self.dt_user_id, self.rebateAggregator))
  File "C:\Users\dt24358\Scripts\Pricing Tool\Rebate_GUI_SQL.py", line 210, in submit_click
    output_df.to_sql(name='PD5', con=self.db2_conn, schema='REBTEAM', if_exists='append', index=False)
  File "C:\Users\dt24358\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2531, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype, method=method)
  File "C:\Users\dt24358\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 460, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype, method=method)
  File "C:\Users\dt24358\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1546, in to_sql
    table.create()
  File "C:\Users\dt24358\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 572, in create
    if self.exists():
  File "C:\Users\dt24358\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 560, in exists
    return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)
  File "C:\Users\dt24358\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1558, in has_table
    return len(self.execute(query, [name, ]).fetchall()) > 0
  File "C:\Users\dt24358\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1426, in execute
    cur = self.con.cursor()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```